# Convert string -> binary -> integer in snowflake

Tags: binary, type-conversion, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sqldatatypes

I am attempting to convert a string to its binary representation and ultimately an integer in Snowflake, but am unable to get the desired result with either `TO_BINARY` or `::BINARY(<n>)`. For example, I am able to do what I want in postgres with the following code

```
SELECT ('x' || 'abcd')::BIT(32)
```

which returns `10101011110011010000000000000000`  as desired.

I want to get the same result in Snowflake, but can't. I have tried both of the following, but simply get the same string returned (e.g. `ABCD` returned as output)

```
SELECT TO_BINARY('abcd')
...
SELECT 'abcd'::BINARY(32)
```

Comment: Do you have more examples? What's the ultimate goal? Will all strings be at most 32 bits?

Answer (score 1):

> I am attempting to convert a string to its binary representation and
> ultimately an integer in Snowflake

If you need to convert a hex value to integer in Snowflake, it's easy:

```
select TO_NUMBER( 'abcd', 'XXXX' );

43981
```

If you need to convert a hex value to bits, Snowflake does not have a native function but it's possible to write a JavaScript function:

```
create or replace function convert_to_bits( decimal_value float, size float )
returns string
language javascript
as $$
  var res = parseInt(DECIMAL_VALUE).toString(2);
  return res + "0".repeat( SIZE - res.length );
$$;

select convert_to_bits(TO_NUMBER( 'abcd', 'XXXX' ), 32) ;

10101011110011010000000000000000
```